# Updating already created object

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a inheritance scheme in an sqlalchemy (this is a sample code, I guess the logic is clear):

```
class Base:
    @classmethod
    def generate(cls, somedata):
        base = Base(...)
        # populating Base class fields here
        ...
        session.add(base)
        session.flush()
        return base

class Child(Base):
    @declared_attr
    def area(self):
        return Base.__table__.c.get('field', Column(Float))
    @classmethod
    def generate(cls):
        base = super(Child, cls).generate(cls, somedata)
        # not sure if I need this or not. It doesn't matter it seems
        # base.__class__ = cls 
        base.area = 10.5
```

After this code I have a table with all needed columns and Base class fields are populated. Child class fields ('area') are empty.
Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Your logic is somewhat unclear. It is questionable if you should be always explicitly creating an instance of Base in generate. This begs the question "what are you trying to accomplish" and would require a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You're also passing cls to generate in the child, though using super, which should raise an error.

Comment: The thing is, I don't wanna duplicate a "base" class part of generate in each child. So I'm creating a base first and then and populate with needed date inside child class. What's unclear? Are there some pattern to make it clearer?

Comment: For starters that's not how inheritance works. You don't create an instance of Base first, initialize, and promote to Child in child's generate in the fashion you've done. Consider using the passed cls parameter in your factory method. And as said before, the way you're calling super's generate in child should raise an error. Your edit made it clear that your issue stems from how you explicitly use Base in your factory method instead of the cls parameter. You set the attribute area of an instance of **Base**, not of an instance of Child.

Comment: It'd also probably be better not to couple adding the instance to DB in Base.generate. Do you commit the additional changes from Child.generate? Let the generate factories simply return generated instances and the caller handle persistence. All in all have you read the [inheritance docs of SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/inheritance.html), or is Base meant to be a [mixin / custom base class](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/mixins.html)?

Comment: Base is a class with polymorphic_identity on some field. I need several child classes which extend Base with different fields. I have area column in my SQL table, but it's empty. Should I somehow cast Base to Child? Code works without any errors. Generate function is called from outside (that's why it's classmethod) to generate items of selected class like Child.generate(input).

Comment: This is something you should include in the question, not in comments. Did you read how to create an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? It's hard to give answers when you have to guess about what's actually going on. Python has no cast in that sense. Use the **cls** parameter in Base.generate as well, so that it'll create an instance of **Child**, when called from Child's generate. Currently you simply set a new attribute area on an instance of Base, which is not a mapped attribute.

Comment: So I should not create base = Base() but instead use base = cls()? And I don't need a constructor in a child class with it's new fields right? Just inherit a base class constructor? And what with the string base.__class__ = cls? Won't it change a class to child for me?